How to use Dynamic Components in Svelte 5 with Runes?
I have the following code:
<script lang="ts">
  import type { SpaceAmenities } from "$src/spaces.d";
  import {
    Computer,
    Plug,
    Printer,
    Box,
    Droplet,
    Wifi,
    CornerDownRight,
    Icon,
  } from "lucide-svelte/icons";

  interface Props {
    amenity: SpaceAmenities;
  }
  let { amenity, ...restProps }: Props = $props();

  const amenityMap: Record<SpaceAmenities, typeof Icon> = {
    Computers: Computer,
    Outlets: Plug,
    Printing: Printer,
    Rooms: Box,
    "Water Fountains": Droplet,
    WiFi: Wifi,
  };
</script>

<svelte:component
  this={amenityMap[amenity] ?? CornerDownRight}
  class="h-fit w-fit scale-75"
  {...restProps}
/>

When moving to runes with Svelte 5, I get the error that svelte:component is deprecated. What's the desired what to address using this={} for components if they are loaded dynamically? I would rather not do a huge list of if-else in the body.

The kind people from the Svelte Discord helped me with this one.
You'll want to create a constant to alias the component and then use that in the template.
e.g.
const Amenity = amenityMap[amenity] ?? CornerDownRight;

<Amenity class="h-fit w-fit scale-75" {...restProps} />

